# BarChart X-Value does not correspond with Y-Value

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart, axis-labels

I've got the following `BarEntry` List:

```
for (Map.Entry<Date, Float> keyVal : allIncTypesWithAmount.entrySet()) {
    long timeToDays = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(keyVal.getKey().getTime());
    float perDay = timeToDays/30;
    values.add(new BarEntry(perDay,keyVal.getValue()));
}
```

Which results in following values:

```
Tue Feb 01 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 2005 value 47.0
Mon Nov 01 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 2021 value 12.0
Mon Apr 01 02:00:00 GMT+02:00 2013 value 76.0
Tue Feb 01 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 2022 value 50.0
```

My `XAxis ValueFormatter`:

```
public class BarChartXAxisValueFormatter extends ValueFormatter 
{

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy", Locale.GERMANY);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    
    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {

        float timeToDays = value * 30;
        long emissionsMilliSince1970Time =  TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis((long) timeToDays) ;
        return sdf.format(getBeginOfMonth(new Date(emissionsMilliSince1970Time)));
    }
    
    
    public static Date getBeginOfMonth(Date d ) {
        calendar.setTime(d);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        return calendar.getTime();
    }

}
```

The current chart looks like this:

[image: current chart]

That's not how I expected it to be.

I'm trying that my chart to look like this:

[image: expected output]

Basically, my aim is to ALIGN the X-Value towards the Y-Bar.
Of course, if there are many X-Values it wont be possible, but since there are only 4 bars, I want that all 4 X-Value align with the Y-Bar.

Few things I tried:

- xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
- setting maxLabelCount

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numbers 1,2,3,4,5 etc. as the x value instead of date.
Each number should represend a date:

```
0 value 47.0
1 value 12.0
2 value 76.0
3 value 50.0
```

Define the `strings`, which will be shown for the x value:

```
ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<>();
xVals.add("04/2020");
xVals.add("06/2020");
xVals.add("11/2020");
xVals.add("01/2021");
```

Pass the List to the `ValueFormatter`:

```
new ValueFormatter(xVals));
```

Last but not least, set the granularity:

```
xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
```